# Probability of picking two models that are your favorite in random selection?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random

> A phone store has items consisting of 5 models of iPhones, 4
>   models of Samsung, 8 models of LG, and 7 models of
>   HTC. You're asked you to go and purchase 3 iPhones, 2
>   Samsungs, 2 LGs, and 4 HTCs.
>
> i) In how many ways can you purchase these if you do not
>   want to select more than one of any model?
>
> **ii) There are HTC and iPhone models that you really wanted. What is the probability that those two phone models were selected during your random selection?**

I found for a) that there are 58800 ways to make this purchase after multiplying combinations of each phone type.

I'm trying to understand how I can do b). I know that there are 7 HTC models to choose from. I will pick 4 different HTC models without replacement, and order doesn't matter. So the total number of outcomes of picking 4 HTC models from 7 is 7C4 which is equal to 35. Since each HTC model has a 1/7 chance of being picked, would my probability of picking my favorite modem be 1/35?

And if I follow that logic for the iPhone, my probability would be 1/10. And so what I need to find is

P(Picking fav iPhone AND picking fav HTC) = 1/35 * 1/10 ?

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You have chosen four HTC phones out of seven available, so the chance any specific model is chosen is $4/7$

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to figure out on top of that the probability that my favorite specific model is chosen.

Comment: And that is exactly what I answered. There are seven phones there,of which you randomly select four.  The favorite one (like all the rest) has $4/7$ chance of being chosen.

Comment: Would the probability be just 4/7, or 4/35?

Comment: How can it be $4/35$?  You are fixated on how many groups of four phones there are.  A specific phone is in $20$ of those $35$ groups, so if you pick a whole group at random the chance it is in the group is $20/35=4/7$.  If you don't believe it, list the $35$ cases and count.

Comment: How do we know a specific phone is in 20 of the 35 groups? I think this is the part that is confusing me. I get what you're saying now, but how did you get 20 without manually counting?

Comment: It is $6 \choose 3$.  If you choose your favorite phone you have to choose three of the other six.  If you don't choose your favorite phone, you have to choose four of the other six, which can be done in $15$ ways.